# How to check if whole sentence is capitalized

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to set a condition to check if an input sentence is capitalized.

```
puts "Whats your name?"
name = gets.chomp
while (input == "I love you aunty, I have to go now") == false do
  puts "Say something"
  input = gets.chomp.to_s
  if (input == input.capitalize)
    puts "SHOW SOME RESPECT"
  elsif input == input.upcase
    puts "SPEAK UP"
  end
end
```

When a single string is entered, it shows `SHOW SOME RESPECT`, but when multiple strings are entered. It returns `say something`.

Comment: Can you please include some of your sample inputs in the question? by the way, don't use `<br>` to add newlines. Just use the return key and format the whole code block with control/command K

Comment: And format your ruby. People will put as much time into an answer as you put into the question

Comment: What do you mean by "capitalize a sentence"? If you do it in the sense of the method `capitalize`, `"I love you aunty, I have to go now"` for example would become `"I love you aunty, i have to go now"`.

Comment: Please post few samples you have tried, the result you want to achieve is not clear.

Comment: @BenjaminWong : What do you mean by "multiple strings"? By the way, the `to_s` after `chomp` is unneccessary, and a condition of the form `(A==B)==false`, which you have in your *while*, is easier to read if you write it as `A!=B`.

Comment: @BenjaminWong : Also, when you enter your while loop, the variable `input` has no value.